# First appearance of a bizarre/opposite version of the original character?

Tags: first-appearance, trope

Many of the shows/movies sometimes have a character which is the counterpart of a certain character. Both characters' appear in the same show/movie.

The bizarre character usually have stark similarities in terms of looks and habits with few behavioral differences. **The bizarre character may or may not play the role of antagonist.**

Here are some examples.

**Friends:** Russ vs. Ross

**Seinfeld:** Bizarro Jerry, George, Kramer vs. Real Jerry, George, Kramer

**The Simpsons:** Lester and Eliza vs. Bart and Lisa

http://avclubmedia.s3.amazonaws.com/video/10301/sd.mp4

Which was the first such bizarre/opposite character appearing in a movie/tv show? (along with the original character of course)

Comment: This is **ancient**. Plot Doubles have been around for decades in fiction & film. Price & The Pauper, Prisoner of Zenda etc....as well as the Evil Twin trope.

Comment: It's a theatrical work, so I write it in the comments, but I think the first (known) work with two twins with different personality is [Menaechmi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menaechmi), from the Latin playwright Plauto.

Answer (score 6):

The first popular reference obviously pre-dates TV or movies, so it being picked up in audio visual format is not surprising.

The 1840s book - the Man in the Iron Mask, by Three Musketeers author, Alexandre Dumas, was first made into a movie back in 1939 (and a few other times since then), and was probably one of the earlier uses of the good/evil twin theme that is so common.

[Man Behind the Iron Mask (1939) - IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0031619)

Answer (score 1):

How about I Dream of Jeannie with Jeannie and her sister. (Not sure if that's the oldest)

Comment: Mentioning from when it was could be of help, though.

Comment: Just to be clear, we're not just talking about Barbara Eden's "twins" that were featured in every episode, right?

Comment: Barbara Eden also played her own twin sister who had the opposite of Jeannie's personality.  This was in 1968.  I did not think it would be the oldest, but I would nominate it as the cutest, acknowledging that it was comical.

Answer (score 1):

*[Mirror, Mirror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror,_Mirror_(Star_Trek:_The_Original_Series))* - an episode of *Star Trek: TOS* features several characters with their opposites.